# Is there a way to forbidden access `window.top` from nested iframe provided by `file://` protocol in electron?

Tags: electron, cross-domain, content-security-policy

For example:

- Electron main entry is `file://main.html`

  - Nested iframe entry is `file://sub.html`

In `file://sub.html` context can access `window.top` context of `main.html`, I know the reason is for the Same-origin-policy `file://`.

Is there any solution to forbidden access `window.top` under the same `file://` protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.top.location.href` is accessible to assign from inside iframe independently SOP. If you wish to restrict that behaviour, use `<iframe sandbox="..allow_flags.."` and allow [what you need](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) except `allow-top-navigation` flag.

Alternatively you can use [`sanbox` directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/sandbox) of Content Security Policy. It supports the same flags, but will affect not only iframes, but the page published it itself.